# Should I use Intellij IDEA 14 Ultimate or Android Studio in that special case?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, ide

As an eclipse user, I am very new to Intellij and also to Android Studio and now I will start developing an app that will be comunicating with a JAX-RS Webservice.
So I wanna know your opinion, shoud I start the development using Android Studio or just stick with the regular Intellij IDEA Ultimate? What are the benefits of each case? What will I be missing?

Comment: As of today, Android studio actually functions, so I guess this would be my immediate solution. plus I'm not even sure the Android plugin would support all the features as Android studio will, and that there would not be any conflicts... better safe then sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate has some additional code insight support for JAX-RS which is not available in Android Studio, and it does include the Android development features from Android Studio. So if you already have an IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate license, I would recommend to just keep using it.